# How to convert a full date to a short date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I have a date like this Monday, January 9, 2010

I now want to convert it to

1/9/2010  mm/dd/yyyy

I tried to do this

```
    var startDate = "Monday, January 9, 2010";
    var convertedStartDate = new Date(startDate);
    var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1
    var day = convertedStartDate.getDay();
    var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
    var shortStartDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

However it must be thinking the date is in a different format since day returns 1 instead of 9.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `getDay()` method returns a number to indicate the day in week (0=Sun, 1=Mon, ... 6=Sat). Use `getDate()` to return  a number for the day in month:

```
var day = convertedStartDate.getDate();
```

If you like, you can try to add a custom format function to the prototype of the `Date` object:

```
Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function(){
    return (this.getMonth() + 1) + 
    "/" +  this.getDate() +
    "/" +  this.getFullYear();
}
```

After doing this, you can call `formatMMDDYYY()` on *any* instance of the `Date` object. Of course, this is just a very specific example, and if you really need it, you can write a generic formatting function that would do this based on a formatting string, kinda like java's SimpleDateeFormat (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

(tangent: the `Date` object always confuses me... `getYear()` vs `getFullYear()`, `getDate()` vs `getDay()`, `getDate()` ranges from 1..31, but `getMonth()` from 0..11

It's a mess, and I always need to take a peek. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Cool that worked. But how can I set it to always do the mm/dd/yyyy since I always want this in that date format no matter what the client set. Like I know I am printing it in the format I want but I am not sure if how it would react to the conversion if it would try to put it in the client format.

Comment: I am still not sure if I need to be concerned about other date formats. Maybe I have to post a new question.

Comment: `Date` is just a class for representing date/time values. It has a number of methods that return a string representation, but your desired format is simply not there. The format you created is not a `Date` object: it's a string, you just created it with data coming out of the `Date` object. You can try to add your own formatting method to the prototype of the `Date` object. I'll edit my answer to show how.

Comment: @Cory Mawhorter "Don't forget": I didn't. I wrote: "but getMonth() from 0..11". Maybe you shouldn't forget to read before you comment. "Don't link to w3schools!" < why not? They explain these points really well.

Comment: Note that you'll want to do `return (this.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +  this.getDate() + "/" +  this.getFullYear();` if you want the month to be correct (since, as Roland mentioned, `getMonth()` returns 0..11)

Answer (score 77):

Here you go:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
```

That's it !!

you can use it on any date object

let's say.. you have an object called "currentDate"

```
var currentDate = new Date(); //use your date here
currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // "en-US" gives date in US Format - mm/dd/yy
```

(or)

If you want it in local format then

```
currentDate.toLocaleDateString(); // gives date in local Format
```

Comment: please avoid using toLocaleDateString in IE 11.

Comment: @CharlieNg how come? At a glance, it looks like it's working for me in IE 11.

Comment: IE 11 issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11

Comment: Ok, if I ever teleport into the past I will not use toLocaleDateString on IE 11

Comment: One thing to look out for is time conversion offsets, which can lead to unexpected results, e.g.: `new Date('2021-09-09').toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // returns "9/8/2021"`

Answer (score 58):

Built-in `toLocaleDateString()` does the job, but it will remove the leading 0s for the day and month, so we will get something like "1/9/1970", which is not perfect in my opinion. To get a proper format `MM/DD/YYYY` we can use something like:

```
new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
})
```

**Alternative**: We can get similar behavior using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` which has decent [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat_format). Similar to `toLocaleDateString()`, we can pass an object with options:

```
const date = new Date('Dec 2, 2021') // Thu Dec 16 2021 15:49:39 GMT-0600
const options = {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
}
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date) // '12/02/2021'
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvotes since this is built-in functionality in JS. I don't understand why someone would prefer using external libraries instead of built in features.

Comment: I am with you on this.

Comment: How can you use the local datetime string with those options? There isn't an overload for just options and also named parameters doesn't seem to work?

Comment: The syntax is `dateObj.toLocaleDateString([locales[, options]])`.
You can find all the options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 8):

```
var d = new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Comment: Code does the trick, but as @N.Wouda states, it would be better with some sort of explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`date.toLocaleDateString('en-US')` works great.  Here's some more information on it:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the date to be shown in the type='time' field.

The normal conversion skips the zeros and the form field does not show the value and puts forth an error in the console saying the format needs to be yyyy-mm-dd.

Hence I added a small statement (check)?(true):(false) as follows:

```
makeShortDate=(date)=>{
yy=date.getFullYear()
mm=date.getMonth()
dd=date.getDate()
shortDate=`${yy}-${(mm<10)?0:''}${mm+1}-${(dd<10)?0:''}${dd}`;
return shortDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question posted long long time ago, the proper way to do this is:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat("en").format(new Date())
```

Any way, the Intl (international) object has many options you can pass to like to enforce tow digits etc.
You all can look at it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a shorter method to access the date in DD/MM/YYYY format:

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(['ban', 'id']).format(new Date()));
```

Even you can get only part of a day like "Afternoon, morning, night, etc.."

Answer (score -2):

I was able to do that with :

```
var dateTest = new Date("04/04/2013");
dateTest.toLocaleString().substring(0,dateTest.toLocaleString().indexOf(' '))
```

the 04/04/2013 is just for testing, replace with your Date Object.

Comment: This was Good for a quick and dirty fix, always loved one liners:
For current date!
(new Date()).toLocaleString().substring(0,(new Date()).toLocaleString().indexOf(' '))

Answer (score -2):

You could do this pretty easily with my [date-shortcode](https://github.com/kodie/date-shortcode) package:

```
const dateShortcode = require('date-shortcode')

var startDate = 'Monday, January 9, 2010'
dateShortcode.parse('{M/D/YYYY}', startDate)
//=> '1/9/2010'
```

Answer (score -10):

Try this:

```
new Date().toLocaleFormat("%x");
```

Comment: This is not a standard.
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat): 
_This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future._

Comment: toLocaleString and toLocaleFormat are now obsolete and perhaps even deprecated