# IE 11 issue with JavaScript toLocaleDateString() formatting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the JavaScript Date function toLocaleDateString() to format my date to look like `8/13/2014`, but for some reason when I try to send this value via an API call by doing a `JSON.stringify` and then AJAXing the value, IE decides to change the actual value to be `?8?/?30?/?2014`.. This obviously causes errors on the back end.

Why does IE do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you've got some character encoding issues. Exactly what they are is hard to say; make sure your pages, your server, and your database are all in agreement as to what character encoding is in use.

Comment: Not sure where this would be set though? All should be UTF-8 I believe. Do you think it is `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: The problem wouldn't be caused by `JSON.stringfy`, though it is not clear how and why you're doing that. You can use the browser's "Network" tab in the developer console to look at the HTTP headers.

Comment: Yeah I have been looking at the headers and the content-type is `application/json; charset=utf-8`.. We use `JSON.stringify` because we have an ASP .NET backend that uses JSON Deserializer to map the JSON to a class

Comment: the page must be set to utf-8, not just the ajax

Comment: It already is set to utf-8

Comment: Right now my only solution was to convert all of my dates to be in the form `mm/dd/yyyy` which would make `8/13/2014` be `08/13/2014`...This is a workaround but still doesn't answer the question why this was occurring in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's a bug that was introduced in IE 11. IE 11 uses Unicode chars, so what you see is [U+200E 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)

What you can do as a temporary solution to fix this issue is to replace that char. Like this:

```
console.log((new Date()).toLocaleDateString().replace(/\u200E/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the answer here:
[ToLocaleDateString() changes in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

> You shouldn't be using a function intended to format something for locale-specific human display and expect the output to be machine parsable. Any of the output of toLocaleString, toLocaleDateString, or toLocaleTimeString are meant for human-readable display only. (As Bergi clarified in comments, toString is also meant for human display, but ECMA §15.9.4.2 says it should round-trip)

Although the function returns a string, it's only human-readable and is never appropriate for machine parsing. I'm not 100% sure what encoding it is for IE, but although it looks like a string, underneath it uses a different encoding.

For date formatting, you may wish to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), or just write your own formatting function.