# IE charset encoding issue with JavaScript Date functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Could someone please explain why IE has a bug when trying to use String functions on a Date function that uses the "Locale"? I think it has something to do with encoding of the characters.

Check this out  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd2utqpz/2/) in both IE and Chrome and you will see that in Chrome we get 4 (the correct index) and in IE we get 8. Does this have to do with ascii vs. unicode? If so, should this be a bug in IE?

```
var date = new Date();

var str = date.toLocaleTimeString();
jQuery('#a').text(str);

jQuery('#b').text(str.lastIndexOf(":"));

str = date.toTimeString();
jQuery('#c').text(str);
jQuery('#d').text(str.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

**Screen shot of IE 11 jsFiddle output**

[image: Screen shot of IE 11 jsFiddle output]

Comment: It works perfectly well for me in IE10.  What exactly does the locale time string look like in IE?

Comment: Try IE 11? That is what I am using

Comment: What does the time string look like?

Comment: They look the exact same, `‎9‎:‎15‎:‎42‎ ‎AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p0pno4kr/) For whatever reason, the IE 11 string has a bunch of extra Unicode "left-to-right mark" characters embedded in it.

The code I added was

```
var s = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
    s  += str.charCodeAt(i) + ' ';
$('#c').text(s);
```

and an accompanying `<h4>` like the others.

[Also see this other Stackoverflow question on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

Comment: So would this technically be a bug in IE 11? It just seems very annoying to have to do this encoding conversion to all these strings just because IE is incompetent.

Comment: @MattHintzke well it's certainly weird, but I'm not sure you could call it a "bug".  There are no firm rules on what the return value from that API should be, and there's nothing technically wrong with including those characters. (It seems dumb though.)

Comment: @MattHintzke note that if you need access to the individual "pieces" of the timestamp, the Date API provides that.

Answer (score 1):

By definition `Date.toLocaleTimeString()` produces output according to user's preferences/defaults.

So the result (position of `:` ) can vary on different platforms, locales and even time of the day.

This is how Korean time looks like for example:

```
"오후 12:00:00"
```

Apparently in your case Chrome and IE have different opinion on default locale formatting.

If you have any code that relies on position of `:` in toLocaleTimeString() it must be refactored to something more reliable.

In some locales/settings toLocaleTimeString() may not contain `:` at all.