# parseInt not working with data from an Array created from a spitted Date inside Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parseint

I have a date that I am converting to LocaleDateString and then splitting it into an array inside an angulrajs controller. When I try to convert to int the elements in the array I get NaN. The characters in the array are numbers but the parse is not working.

How can I parse that data properly?

Code:

```
var dateLocal = $scope.startDate.toLocaleDateString(); //Has this ‎6‎/‎5‎/‎2015
var dateSplitted = dateLocal.split("/"); //Has [6,5,2015]
var month = parseInt(dateSplitted[0]);  //HERE If I use parseIntI get NaN originally it has 6
var day = dateSplitted[1];//Has 5
var year = dateSplitted[2]; Has 2015
```

I want to be aple to convert to string month day and year.

Comment: remember to use the radix in parseInt eg: parseInt( val, 10 )

Comment: @Devsined are you seeing this problem in IE11? Are you seeing it in other browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21413757/3149036

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rely on [`toLocaleDateString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.6), which is implementation dependent:

> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are
>   implementation-dependent

The problem is that your browser returns a string with some [left-to-right marks (U+200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm).

See the difference:

```
var str1 = "6", // "\u0036"             <-- OK
    str2 = "‎6‎"; // "\u200e\u0036\u200e" <-- Your "corrupted" string
parseInt(str1); // 6
parseInt(str2); // NaN
```

So you shouldn't trust the value returned by that method. Instead, use date methods to get the day, month and year.

Comment: And parseInt returns NaN if the first character it finds is not a digit. So you have to trim non-digits with a regex.

Comment: @Oriol How did you know it was left-to-right marks?

Comment: @tavnab OP says "*Has this ‎6‎/‎5‎/‎2015*". This string contains those U+200E.

Comment: @Oriol I'm sorry, but I don't see it in the OP's sample code/comments, and inspecting this page's source doesn't show anything but "6/5/2015" (with no RTL marks) in the HTML. Can you tell me how you noticed the 2 characters?

Comment: @tavnab Browsers display the character, so paradoxically it can't be seen. Copy that text and paste it in a text editor and you will see it.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol; for future readers, apparently this is a [bug reported for IE11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811107/ie-11-javascript-date-tolocaledatestring-returns-a-string-that-contains-left-to-right-mark-characters-which-may-not-be-used-to-create-a-new-date)

Comment: The issue of using get day is I am getting the days and months with the time zone offset and then was painful just to compare my date with other date in UTC

Comment: If I try $scope.startDate.getDay() and $scope.startDate.getMonth() I get 5 and 5 using 6/5/2015. There there is rabit whole on how the datepicker of angularui is working with javascript date.

Comment: @Devsined If you want UTC, there are `getUTCDate`, `getUTCMonth` and `getUTCFullYear`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer why you are getting `NaN` in your code, but instead of converting the date object to a string and parsing the parts, you can get the parts of the date directly using [`Date.prototype.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), [`Date.prototype.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) (day-of-month), and [`Date.prototype.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

Comment: The issue with this oslution is I am getting the offset of the timezone and later I cannot compare with other dates

Comment: Apologies, it's not clear why using these functions won't work from your example. The result of calling the above functions on `$scope.startDate` is equivalent to getting the string & parsing it, but shorter. If you also need to extract the timezone, you can use [`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Can you please clarify if I'm misunderstanding your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, and it seemed to work fine for me. For your dateLocal, I just replaced your value with `var dateLocal = new Date().toLocaleDateString();` because I didn't know what value was loaded from your scope. When I did this, the code loaded fine, so you may want to double check the nature of the variable you are loading from the scope.