# Javascript - encodeURI() returing different results in different browsers

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, urlencode, microsoft-edge

I use encodeURI() to encode a php request url, it works perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't in IE/Edge.

The actual url is:
`http://localhost/get.php?id=e_e2&title=e2&desc=just a note&stime=6/12/2015, 1:00:00 AM&etime=15/12/2015, 1:00:00 PM`

What Firefox returns is (works):
`http://localhost/get.php?id=e_HO%20Event%201&title=HO%20Event%201&desc=This%20is%20just%20a%20test%20event%20of%20this%20handover%20only&stime=6/12/2015,%201:00:00%20AM&etime=10/12/2015,%201:00:00%20PM`

What IE returns (Break the php code):
`http://localhost/get.php?id=e_HO%20Event%201&title=HO%20Event%201&desc=This%20is%20just%20a%20test%20event%20of%20this%20handover%20only&stime=%E2%80%8E6%E2%80%8E/%E2%80%8E12%E2%80%8E/%E2%80%8E2015%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8E1%E2%80%8E:%E2%80%8E00%E2%80%8E:%E2%80%8E00%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8EAM&etime=%E2%80%8E10%E2%80%8E/%E2%80%8E12%E2%80%8E/%E2%80%8E2015%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8E1%E2%80%8E:%E2%80%8E00%E2%80%8E:%E2%80%8E00%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8EPM`

I have tried to decode what IE returns but it caused me a lots of problems!, so is there an alternatives to encodeURI() ?, FF seems to work even if I dont encode the url, where IE works if I copy the FF encoded url to it!

---

update:
example code [link](http://jsbin.com/zekefuteze/edit?html,output)

I think it has something to do with toLocaleString()

---

Final update:

As few answered, it was some weard marks in the link "appears only in IE!" I had to filter and changes what my php script date format to remove the comma

```
function FixLocaleDateString(localeDate) {
    var newStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < localeDate.length; i++) {
        var code = localeDate.charCodeAt(i);
            if (code != 44 && code != 8206 ) {
                newStr += localeDate.charAt(i);
            }
    }
        return newStr;
}
```

I found this function in another answer and modify it: [ToLocaleDateString() changes in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

Comment: Try encodeURIComponent() for special characters

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP not, it will mess up the whole url and will not work anywhere

@MaxZuber this is the code
`var phphref = 'http://localhost/get.php?id=e_'+event.title+'&title='+event.title+'&desc='+event.description+'&stime='+stime+'&etime='+etime;
 
 console.log('url only:');
 console.log(phphref); //fine
 
 function myFunction(uri) {
 var res = encodeURI(uri);
 //console.log(res);
 return res;
 }

var calfile = myFunction(phphref);
console.log('encoded:');
console.log(calfile); //fine in ff, not in ie !`
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not `encodeURI` (though as others have pointed out, you should never use `encodeURI`, but rather encode individual components with `encodeURIComponent` and then join them together).

The problem is that the dates for some reason contains lots of `U+200E "LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK"` characters (which are invisible, but still present), which once encoded become `%E2%80%8E`.

Show us where/how you get the times, or filter the time strings to remove those characters before encoding.

Comment: I think I found the problem which causing all that! (maybe), looking at the result of generated url in both browsers I found ther is a missing (,) in IE, which turned out to be because of the toLocaleString(), as in IE it returns a different value if you are not in US.
now according to [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)
I used `toLocaleString('en-US');` but its not making any different yet ;\

Comment: My code is too big :\ but I have created this example which have the same problem if you test it in IE/FF
[link](http://jsbin.com/zekefuteze/edit?html,output)

Comment: @et3rnal, I'm not sure I understand why you want to use `toLocaleString` for a date you're going to send to the server, which needs to be parsed by it. `toLocaleString` is meant to be used to convert a date a string that is directly presented to the user. For internal use, I recommend you either use the absolute timestamp value (number of milliseconds since the epoch), or `toISOString` which will deliver a date with a standard formatting you can be sure you can rely on.

Comment: I re-read your answer after I run out of ways, finally I filtered the wired LTR marks as well as the comma! as I cant figure out why IE ignoring it.

now works fine and this is the simple filtering function (I found it in another question and modify it)

`function FixLocaleDateString(localeDate) {
  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < localeDate.length; i++) {
   var code = localeDate.charCodeAt(i);
    if (code != 44 && code != 8206 ) {
     newStr += localeDate.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return newStr;
 }`

Comment: Thanks for the information, I might change it in the future. The reason im using it because its part of a plugin im using.

Comment: If you want to filter a string, there's a much quicker way to do so: `string.replace(/[,\u200e]/g,'')`

Comment: Great will try it now, im looking at the toISOString() and the other getMonth() etc.. do u know if it is possible to construct something like this format 2013-03-16 12:00 AM ?

Comment: Thanks heaps, converted to ISO which solved another problem.

Comment: Nitpicking: your first parenthesis is never closed.

Answer (score 1):

Define a simple `params` object to represent desired URL parameters and glue its items. If there some incorrect characters in the properties, you need to filter them out before `encodeURIComponent()` call.

```
var params = {
  'id': 'e_'.concat(event.title.toString()),
  'title': event.title.toString(),
  'desc': event.description.toString(),
  'stime': stime.toString(),
  'etime': etime.toString()
};

var chunks = [];
for (var property in params) {
  if (params.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    chunks.push(property.concat('=', encodeURIComponent(params[property])));
  }
}
var href = 'http://localhost/get.php?'.concat(chunks.join('&'));

console.log(href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent when you want to encode a URL parameter.

Here is some useful links

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

https://coderwall.com/p/y347ug/encodeuri-vs-encodeuricomponent