# JavaScript new Date().toLocaleString() length

Tags: javascript

In I.E. 11, in the console window, if I type `new Date().toLocaleString()`, I get something like "2/4/2016 9:12:05 AM".  However, if I add `.length`, I get 32.  The string is 19 "readable" characters, so what's up with the 32 and is there an option I can invoke that will give me a string of length 19?

If I type `new Date(new Date().toLocaleString())`, I get [date] Invalid Date, whereas if I type `new Date(new Date("2/4/2016 9:12:05 AM"))` I get a legitimate date.

My locale is "en-US".

Comment: `console.log(new Date().toLocaleString().split("").map(function(c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); }))`

Comment: Also, what locale applies to the tests you're doing?

Comment: en-US (updated question)

Comment: Have you tried typing the code I posted in the comment? That will log the character codes of the date string so that you can check for things like Unicode weirdness.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see the Unicode weirdness.  Now I am looking for a conversion from Unicode.

Comment: [FileFormat.info](http://fileformat.info)

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

Comment: That reference is a good answer.  If you want to write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the lenght of the whole string. 
In this case what this function return is :
Thu Feb 04 2016 17:28:09 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)  <-- 32 chars.
Try to get the new Date as a variable and use it.

var example = new Date();

Comment: What the function returns in your locale is not necessarily the same as what it returns in the locale of the OP.

Comment: Correct, But the format will be always the same.
*if there are no aditional methods 
new Date (); will return your local time and date in this format "Thu Feb 04 2016 17:28:09 GMT+0200"

Comment: The issue is not what new Date() returns, but what toLocaleString() returns.

Comment: I think the whole point of the question is that the OP is seeing something that is *not* the same.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with IE11 as well. I have encountered same issue, fixed it by using below date, this way you do not see any invisible empty character.

```
var cleanDate = (new Date()).toISOString();
```

Here is solution for specific to your problem, if you do not want to use above method of getting date.

```
//Custom extension method to replace all found value.
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
var target = this;
    return target.split(find).join(replace);
};
//Find there is invisible empty character
var emptyCode = (new Date()).toLocaleString().charCodeAt(0);
var cleanDate = undefined;
if(emptyCode === 8206)
{
    //Remove all invisiable empty characters
    cleanDate =(new Date()).toLocaleString().replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(emptyCode),'');
}
```

Extension Method can be found from below post.
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**maybe this solution can help (in dd.mm.yyyy format)**

```
var curDate = new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
```