# String won't convert into date

Tags: javascript, date

Got a problem here that is driving me mad.
2 variables being instantiated as dates, one with a string and one with a hard coded value. If you look at the debug window the value of mString is exactly the same as the hard coded value yet it produces an invalid date.
No idea why but I sure would appreciate any pointers.
I'm using IE 11. It works fine in all other browsers

mString is created like this: -

```
mString = dateParts[2] + "-" + mon.toString() + "-" + dateParts[1]
```

The errors in the console are not related to this

[image: Debug Window]

Comment: Can you show the value of mString?

Comment: It's in the debug window in the attached image

Comment: what in the world is the value of `mString`?

Comment: @Shazoo It is in the debug window, but perhaps the variable is updated elsewhere and isn't in fact "2017-02-07" at the time the `Date` object is instantiated?

Comment: Well, this is not possible. The answer is, value of `mString` is not "2017-02-07" then, maybe it gets changed by something?

Comment: @Shazoo you have errors on the console tab, what are they?

Comment: This should work.You have 7 console errors, are you sure they don't affect on this part ?

Comment: Post your code if possible otherwise there is no way to guess.

Comment: That's very odd. I can't replicate on my IE 11. I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/kkqxt8L9/. Can you try that and see if you get the same result as before with your browser?

Comment: How is `mString` set?  That part of the code is not included in the screencap.  May we see that part of the code?

Comment: Possibly (probably?) a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11

Comment: mString is created by concatenating datepart strings together: 
mString = dateParts[2] + "-" + mon.toString() + "-" + dateParts[1]

Comment: You need to share more code. Is `date1` modified? Is `mString` modified? etc. Sometimes explaining the problem leads to the solution

Comment: @Shazoo That still kind of just pushes the problem further back.  What does `dateParts` contain?  How is it set?  It would be hugely helpful if you could set up a minimal demo.  There's plenty of tools out there to help you do that.  Here's a simple demo that kind of tries to replicate the problem, but it works in IE 11: http://jsbin.com/bomihikeqi/edit?html,output

Comment: @JosephMarikle To be honest the way it's built up is a bit convoluted which is why I didn't post it. But surely a string is a string no matter how it's constructed. They're both the same value in the code above so I thought they should behave the same

Comment: @Shazoo Us asking for more code is less about doubting the nature of how the string is being handled and more about wondering if the string has been changed along the way.  Try a `console.log(mString)` immediately before the `new Date()`, if that isn't how it works now.  If that spits out the same `2017-02-07` value, there's something deeper that might even be a bug with IE at play.  It's unlikely but possible.

Comment: Still we don't know how/when variables are modified or where is your breakpoint

Comment: Don't post images, post code. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can't post code that replicates the issue, or even describe it accurately, others can't help.

Comment: BTW, best to ask permission before you use [*someone else's image*](http://www.e-cultura.sapo.pt/artigo/21452) as your avatar, unless you really are that person.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to work, I have tested the below in both IE11 and Chrome, do both alerts work for you?

```js
var mString = "2017-02-07";
var d1 = new Date(mString);
var d2 = new Date("2017-02-07")

alert(d1);
alert(d2);
```

Comment: That isn't what the OP is doing. Using the Date constructor to parse strings isn't recommended.  ISO 8601 format date only strings are treated as UTC, so for hosts set to a time zone west of Greenwich the above will create a date for 6 February, not 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var pattern = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/;
var date = new Date(mString.replace(pattern,'$1-$2-$3'));
```

Comment: lol.  Nice idea.  I feel like there's some other, simple reason why the stated behaviour is happening though.  This might fix OP's problem; but until he/she responds to the comments above, it's too hard to tell; but nice thinking outside the box.  However, shouldn't that third grouping be a `\d{2}`?

Comment: Sorry, it still say invalid date

Comment: Yes.. the third group should be 2! :) tnx

Comment: No, don't do that.  Using the Date constructor to parse strings isn't recommended and most will deliver incorrect results for the pattern suggested (if they parse it at all).