# Ag-grid - Exported excel does not parse string to date format in IE

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, ag-grid

I am exporting `ag-grid` data to excel which has few `date` type columns. On opening exported file, I observed that `date` type columns are not auto-formatted to 'Date' format when exported from `IE`. Same thing works fine in `Chrome`.Below is the code which formats the date string -

```
exportData: function() {
        var vm = this;
        var params = {
            fileName : vm.pageTitle + '.csv',
            processCellCallback  : function(params) { 
             if (params.value) {
                 if(params.column.colId === "endDate" || params.column.colId === "startDate"){
                    return params.value.toLocaleDateString();
                 }
             }
             return params.value;
            }
        };
        vm.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);     
    }
```

**Below is the excel screenshot for IE -** The General format should be `Date`

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just as clarification, you are exporting your data to a csv file, then asking excel to open that file... and since csv files don't contain datatype definition, Excel would need to *infer* datatype... did you say that exporting from chrome works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11), `toLocaleDateString()` behaves funky in IE. My guess is that it is adding a [zero width character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). I guess this because I have used the zero width character to force formatting in excel as general (my use case was  `1/1` needed to stay that way and not transform to `1-jan` like excel wanted to do)

So to solve your problem, you could either format the date yourself to ensure what characters are getting placed, or you could regex out any whitespace characters with:

`.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\s/g,'')`

Comment: Thanks @Jarod. Your answer helped. It's indeed a problem with `toLocaleDateString()`. Now I have formatted the date as `(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear()` and it works.