# javascript set dropdown value to month not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am using the following code to set a drop-down value to the current month, it is working in Chrome and Edge but in IE 11 the value is empty.

```js
month = currentDate.toLocaleString(locale, {month:"short"})
document.getElementById("month").value = month
```

month contains the value "Jul" and is of type string, and I can set it as the value of a text box.

If I manually assign month = "Jul", it does set the value on the drop-down.

Comment: Have you added a `console.log("month is: " + month)` to verify that `.toLocaleString()` is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: yes, it is "Jul" which is what I would expect

Comment: Well one string that's really `"Jul"` is the same as any other string that's `"Jul"`, so what you're describing makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEs `toLocalString()` adds some [invisible Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11) to the string so the value of the dropdown-option and the value of `month` are not actually the same.

If it won't cause cross-locale compatibility issues then you can trim these characters with `replace`.

Alternatively, if you know the order of your dropdown list then get the month as a number and use `selectedIndex`

```js
currentDate = new Date()
locale = 'en-US'
month = currentDate.toLocaleString(locale, {month:"short"})
document.getElementById("month").value = month.replace(/[^A-z]/g,'')

// Alternatively
//document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex = currentDate.getMonth();
```

```html
<select name="dates" id="month">
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option value="Mar">Mar</option>
<option value="Apr">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">Jun</option>
<option value="Jul">Jul</option> 
<option value="Aug">Aug</option> 
<option value="Sep">Sep</option> 
<option value="Oct">Oct</option>
<option value="Nov">Nov</option> 
<option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select>
```