# IE 11 - Date is not working

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-11

1. `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');  // "‎8‎/‎17‎/‎2018"`
2. `new Date("8/17/2018") //valid date`
3. `new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US'))  // Invalid Date`

I am trying to create `date` from `local date 
string (see screenshot)` but its not working in `IE11 only`. It works with normal `date string` though.

I know something wrong with `"" double quotes` but not able to get it working.

Any suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: The string should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Same issue with ```momentjs```

Comment: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it can be done like this

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US').replace(/[^ -~]/g,''))
```

[image: Snapshot from ie11]

[**Reference Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

Comment: ```It worked ```

Comment: @jackjop—you don't seem to know what you're looking at. The output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, browsers are not required to be able to parse it and you should not expect that they can. There are many strings that can be generated from *toLocaleString* that can't be parsed by any browser, much less IE. On the other hand, the output of *toString* is now standardised and current browsers are required to parse it.

Comment: @RobG `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US')` and `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US').replace(/[^ -~]/g,'')` will give me the same output (at least in a few browsers I tried, including IE11). So what difference is there between `replace(/[^ -~]/g,'')` and `toString()` in this case? I don't quite understand it. I couldn't find any resources about this problem.

Comment: @jackjop—it's not a good idea to rubbish a product without sound reasons. The key here is that the result of *toLocaleDateString* is implementation dependent and browsers are not required to be able to parse it. The fact that some random code produces a desired result with no idea of how or why it works is not a suitable basis for suggesting its adoption. :-(

Comment: @RobG, I see. So we only need to accept it and have workarounds. Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

just use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for this.

`moment("8/17/2018", "L").format()` would output:
`"2018-08-17T00:00:00+02:00"`

(`+02:00` is my local timezone. you can specify to use utc or another timezone too.)

also keep in mind L is dependent on the timezone profile you installed. this is the default `en` one.

you could also replace `"L"` with `"MM/DD/YYYY"`

the second argument of moment always specifies the format of your input.
it is also able to guess the input but you need to experiment with that.

`.format("L")` is essentially the same but in the output direction.

Comment: "*Use library X*" answers aren't helpful. The OP's question is why the built–in parser doesn't correctly parse the output of *toLocaleDateString* (which is implementation dependent and may differ even with the same language tag).

Comment: while i agree on avoiding "library x" answers, i kindly disagree in case of `Date`. yes you can make stuff work but you can never be 100% certain that your code will run in all browsers if you are relying on automated parsing rather than using `Date` properly. i throw momentjs at people because it removes this usually failing dependency.

Comment: how will smart TV x run your code? how will it run on a playstation vita? what about the samsung browser on old phones? how about opera mini? what about opera mobile?

Comment: they all run momentjs just fine.

Comment: To use any parser, you need to know the format so you can tell the parser what it is. The OP's issue is that the output of *toLocaleDateString* is implementation dependent, so they don't know the format, so can't tell the parser even if they use one that takes a parse format (like moment.js). It's important to tell the OP why they have their issue and how to solve it without a library (since there's no library tag or mention of one). You might include a solution using a library, but your answer shouldn't use only a library not tagged or mentioned in the OP.

Comment: PS. Parsing a date in format MM/DD/YYYY is 2 lines of code that will run in any ECMAScript implementation compliant with ed 1 or later, i.e. any commercial implementation in use. :-)

Comment: ye. it's quite easy if you know what you do.. `var d = "05/10/2018".split("/"); new Date(+d.pop(), +d.shift()-1, +d.shift())` or even using something like Date.UTC...
still.. if this is not the only format one has to deal with. both of us know that.

Comment: "*…this is not the only format one has to deal with*". Exactly. The OP doesn't know what *toLocaleDateString* will produce across every implementation that might run the code, so can't reliably parse it, with or without a library.