# Changing date format using Jquery

Tags: javascript, date

I have date got from a API like this 2018-08-27T09:28:53, now I want to convert it to a format like August 27, 2018.

I have tried using this

```
var d = new Date(val.date);
d = d.toDateString();
```

the above code gives a date like Mon Jul 27 2018. How can I add the comma and separate the month day and year?

Is there a better way to format iso 8601 date to desired format, for me like August 27, 2018.

Comment: Why don't you use momentjs. It has many useful utilities for such kind of conversion. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: @Mahesh because you can do this with pure javascript, check my answer for example. if OP only needs this operation then moment is overkill

Comment: @Mahesh only for this functionality I don't want to include another library, we can do this with just 3 line of code as shown by jackjop

Comment: Your first issue is that not all current browsers will correctly parse "2018-08-27T09:28:53". Do not use the built–in parser. Use a real parser (there are plenty to choose from) and you'll get a formatter thrown in for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be that you use `options` with `toLocaleDateString`

```
var d = new Date(val.date);
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
d = d.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)
```

```js
var d = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log( d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options) );
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IE10 and below, [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, well yeah, I just tested on `IE10`. Doesn't work as you said. but `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US')` gives me `Monday, August 27, 2018`. in this case we can get the substring to get the expected result too. `var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US'); d = d.substr(d.indexOf(',') + 2)`

Comment: @jackjop—the value of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, so you can't guarantee that will work in all hosts.

Comment: @RobG :) you're right. For anyone, in case you have weird resulting strings, please reference this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892913/3729695 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25317146/3729695

Comment: @jackjop Sure, we can do that, another issue of toLocaleDateString already mentioned with RobG, so your solution needs to be use with caution and yeah its short and simple, but I think it's not really global solution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you is to use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/):

```
var date = new Date('2018-08-27');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Or you can Nativity:

```
var dateAr = '2018-08-27'.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[0].slice(-2);

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure js:

```js
let objDate = new Date(),
    month = objDate.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' }),
    day = objDate.getDate(),
    year = objDate.getFullYear()
    
console.log(`${month} ${day}, ${year}`)
```

or

```js
let objDate = new Date(),
    date = objDate.toLocaleString('en-us', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })

console.log(date)
```

[More about toLocaleString.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: `new Date('2018-08-27')` will be parsed as UTC, so return the wrong local date for the host timezone offset around midnight. Some offsets are up to +14 hours, so will continue to show yesterdays date until 2pm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plugin for that, like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), or use following code:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var months = [
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    var d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear();

    return months[m] + ', ' + d + ' ' + y;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```