# Getting date of next Monday in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I got this JS code:

```js
var d = new Date();
  
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
 
  document.write(d);
```

and I want JS to display it in dd/mm/yyyy. How can I do that?

Thank you,
Till

Comment: Please [search](/help/searching) before posting. **Every** conceivable "How do I format this date in JavaScript?" question has been asked and answered long since. Also do thorough research before posting, as even outside SO, this topic is **very** thoroughly covered.

Comment: moment().add( 7, "days" ).format("DD/MM/YYYY"). Don't reinvent the wheel and check out momentJS. (Deja vu today, isn't it?)

Comment: Your solution is previously asked stackoverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript Please search directory before asking the question.

Answer (score -2):

Try this link to W3  Schools date formatting:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

and date methods:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

and check out this previous S/O answer:

[How to convert a full date to a short date in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035699/how-to-convert-a-full-date-to-a-short-date-in-javascript)