# How can I format date being returned from SQL server to a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string being returned from a sql database that looks like this

> Mon Jan 01 1753 12:00:00 GMT-0517 (Eastern Standard Time)

How can I format that string to 01-01-1753 and compare it against other dates 
like 01-01-2010?

At the very least how would I format the date, I should be able to go from there with what I need to do

Comment: Duplicated question. Answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035699/how-to-convert-a-full-date-to-a-short-date-in-javascript

Comment: `new Date(yourString)` will work as expected.

Comment: @JonasWilms, I tried as you mentioned, let retDate = "Mon Jan 01 1753 12:00:00 GMT-0517 (Eastern Standard Time)";
let myDate = new Date(retDate);
console.log(myDate); It just shows the same string

Comment: @chris yes, which means that new Date parsed it correctly, and then showed it to you as if it would be a string (it isn't)

Comment: I went through the solutions in the How to format a JavaScript date and got one that worked